# Understanding that a hypothesis test does not depend on a certain parameter

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a very big doubt regarding a test not depending on $\theta_1$. Suppose I have:

$$(X_i)_{i=1}^{n}, X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\theta, 1), \hbox{ that is } X_i \sim g(x_i, \theta) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \exp[\frac{-1}{2}(x_i - \theta)^2]$$

The joint distribution is given by $f(x;\theta) = (2\pi)^{-n/2} \exp[\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \theta)^2] $

Suppose I have the following hypothesis test with $0<\theta_1$, where $\theta_1$ is fixed but arbitrary (remark: always positive)

$$H_0: \theta = 0\quad \hbox{vs}\quad H_1: \theta = \theta_1$$

By Neyman–Pearson theorem, there is some $k>0$ such that

$$\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : f(x;0)k  < f(x;\theta_1)  \\
    0 & : f(x;0)k  > f(x;\theta_1)
  \end{array}
\right.$$

is a UMP test in the class of tests with size $\alpha = E_0[\phi(X)]$.

$$\hbox{I want to understand why this test does not depend on }\theta_1?$$

$remark:$ $\theta_1$ is positive and fixed but arbitrary. That is, I want to understand if I want to change the parameter $\theta_1$, I will still get the same test exactly. Notice that:

$$k < \frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;0)} \Longleftrightarrow \ln(k) < \frac{n}{2}(2 \theta_1 \bar{x} - \theta_1^{2}) $$

In addition, we can see that

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
k < \frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;0)} & \Longleftrightarrow  \frac{\ln(k)}{n} < \frac{1}{2}(2 \theta_1 \bar{x} - \theta_1^{2}) = \theta_1\bar{x} - \frac{\theta_1^{2}}{2} \\
 & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\ln(k)}{n} + \frac{\theta_1^{2}}{2} < \theta_1\bar{x}\\
& \stackrel{\theta_1 > 0}{\Longleftrightarrow } \frac{\ln(k)}{n\theta_1} + \frac{\theta_1}{2} < \bar{x}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{n}\left[\frac{\ln(k)}{n\theta_1} + \frac{\theta_1}{2}\right] < \sqrt{n}\bar{x}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \tilde{k}(\theta_1) < \sqrt{n}\bar{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then  $\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : \tilde{k}(\theta_1) < \sqrt{n}\bar{x}  \\
    0 & : \tilde{k}(\theta_1) > \sqrt{n}\bar{x}
  \end{array}
\right.$, with $\alpha = E_0[\phi(X)]$. Notice that $Z = \sqrt{n} \bar{X} \sim N(0,1)$. So, to determine the test well, we have to determine the constant $\tilde{k}(\theta_1)$. We will determine the constant $\tilde{k}(\theta_1)$ forcing the test to be of size $\alpha$. Under the null hypothesis, we have:

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\alpha = E_{0}[\phi(X)] & \Longleftrightarrow  P_{0}[\tilde{k}(\theta_1) < Z] = \alpha \\
 & \Longleftrightarrow P_{0}[Z \leq \tilde{k}(\theta_1) ] = 1 -\alpha \\
& \Longleftrightarrow F_Z (\tilde{k}(\theta_1)| \theta = 0) = 1 -\alpha\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \tilde{k}(\theta_1) = F_{Z}^{-1} ( 1- \alpha| \theta = 0)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

And here is my problem, because the $\tilde{k}(\theta_1)$ depends on the parameter $\theta_1$. For example, suppose $\alpha = 0.01$, we have

$$\tilde{k}(\theta_1) = \sqrt{n}\left[\frac{\ln(k)}{n\theta_1} + \frac{\theta_1}{2}\right] = 2.33$$

In other words, if a take some other $\theta_1^{'}>0$, we have other $\tilde{k}(\theta_1^{'})$. And consequently, I will have another test $\phi^{'}(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : \tilde{k}(\theta_1^{'}) < \sqrt{n}\bar{x}  \\
    0 & : \tilde{k}(\theta_1^{'}) > \sqrt{n}\bar{x}
  \end{array}
\right.$

For this purpose, can I adjust the $\tilde{k}(\theta_1)$ by resizing the sample $n$? that is, if I want the $\tilde{k}(\theta_1)$ not to depend on the parameter $\theta_1$, I should just change $n$? but this does not seem to make much sense. Why am I asking this? because in other problems, I really need to vary the parameter $\theta_1 > 0$ and ensure that the test does not depend on $\theta_1$. For example:

$$H_0: \theta \leq 0\quad \hbox{vs}\quad H_1: \theta > 0.$$

Comment: Why do you think this test doesn't depend on $\theta_1$?  It's right there in your formula $f(x;0)k < f(x;\theta_1)$!  If you change $\theta_1$, $f(x;\theta_1)$ will change, so the truth-value of the expression can change too.

Comment: Basically, consider the last line of my question. If I want to find a UMP test, I start testing $\theta = 0$ vs $\theta = \theta_1$, with $\theta_1> 0$ . Once found the test, I would have to note that the test does not depend on $\theta_1$. This procedure is exactly what I wrote at the time of developing my question.

Comment: One answer might be to define well what the expression "test does not depend on paramater $\theta_1$" means. If I say that a test does not depend on the parameter $\theta_1$, it means not to change the signal $>$ in the $\phi$ expression. So in fact, my test does not change its structure, even though I use another parameter $\theta_1^{'}$. But I do not know if this is the correct definition.

Comment: You mean that the "$>$" comparison doesn't change with $\theta_1$?   Why would it?

Comment: Observe this: $\frac{\ln(k)}{n} + \frac{\theta_1^{2}}{2} < \theta_1\bar{x}$. If $\theta_1 >0$, then the $<$ does not change!

Comment: Look at the original formulation of the test:  $k < f(x;\theta_1)/f(x;0)$.  Note that the ratio on the r.h.s. is positive for all values of $x, \theta_1$.  If $f(x;\theta_1)$  is "small" relative to $f(x;0)$, specifically, less than $k$ times it, we won't reject $H_0$, and that's regardless of the sign of $\theta_1$, and conversely for $f(x;\theta_1)$ "large" relative to $f(x;0)$.

Comment: Rejecting or not the null hypothesis depends on the observed values $x$.